# Drakov http status code 404 from ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, http-post, apiblueprint

I use a drakov mock server with an api blueprint md file. I want to send a POST request, but I always get status code 404.

I use a simple jQuery code:

```
var url = "http://localhost:3000/student/1/setfinalcommit";
var data = {first: "exampl"};
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    data: data
});
```

Although it doesn't work with my JS code, it works from curl:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"first" : "exampl"}' http://localhost:3000/student/1/setfinalcommit`

My .md file:

## Message [/student/{userid}/setfinalcommit]

#### Post to the first example [POST]

- Request (application/json)
  First POST example with body

  - Body

    ```
    {"first": "exampl"}
    ```
- Response 200 (application/json;charset=UTF-8)

  - Body

    ```
    {
        "first": "exampl",
        "status": "ok"
    }
    ```

My question is:
Did I mess up the blueprint, or the ajax request?

Thanks!

Comment: not related to 404, but when you specify or event do not specify, there is no need to `stringify` JSON as jQuery has intelligent guess system for getting dataType of data, so you can remove `stringify`. For more [Info on AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: yeah, you are right, that was just a mistake, thanks.

Comment: So you sure you get 404 not 403 or something, from given information it seems its hard to get 404

Comment: Yes, here is the result from chrome console https://www.dropbox.com/s/6o228mc6vw8okos/File%202015.%2012.%2004.%2021%2006%2018.png?dl=0

Comment: As from image it seems `preflight OPTIONS` are being sent, the issue is at backend where its not able to process POST request. checkout some posts related to `preflight OPTIONS`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution!

Comment: ohk.. so it was from backend as I guessed..

Comment: yes, I had to add --autoOptions.... I'm just an idiot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up the backend. I had to start the drakov like this:

```
drakov -f myfile.md --autoOptions
```